# Flutter: Why typecasting fails but for element works in this particular case?

Tags: json, string, flutter, casting

I have developed some kind of modules to ease up converting json data into models. This usually already works well. I can convert various type of maps and lists without problems.

At the moment I faced a weird case. I know that the incoming data is `List<String>`, as this is a list of email addresses. But of course in its raw format, it's currently `List<dynamic>`.

These are my attempts to convert. First:

```
var data = json["emails"]; // works
var list = data as List;   // works
var listStr = list as List<String>; // error

Error message: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast
```

Second:

```
var data = json["emails"]; // works
var list = data as List;   // works
List<String> listStr = list; // error

Error message: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast
```

Third:

```
var data = json["emails"]; // works
var list = data as List;   // works
List<String> listStr = list.map((e) {
  print(e.runtimeType);    // result: String
  return e;
}).toList(); // error

Error message: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
```

Fourth:

```
var data = json["emails"]; // works
var list = data as List;   // works
List<String> listStr = list.map((e) {
  print(e.runtimeType);    // result: String
  print(e.toString().runtimeType); // result: String
  return e.toString();
}).toList(); // success
```

Fifth:

```
var data = json["emails"]; // works
var list = data as List;   // works
List<String> listStr = [for (var email in list) email]; // success
```

Why is this happening? How can I resolve this without adding `.toString()`, because I may have other cases in the future where I might not be converting from json, and the list might not be a simple String object. I just don't understand why, with data type already String, it's not assignable or convertible from dynamic, even though I already use `map().toList()`. The fifth method works at least. But it's still strange.

Comment: If you know all the items in the list to be `String`s, you can use any of these:

`List<String> emails = data.cast<String>();`, `List<String> emails = data.map((e) => e as String).toList();`, `List<String> emails = data.map<String>((e) => e).toList();`

Comment: Ooh okay. I read that `cast` is dangerous to use, but maybe it's okay in cases like this. Thanks!